# what is the best way to extract xml in java object without a schema

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, transformation

I have a fairly complex xml and I don't have a schema for it.
I only wanted to extract a few things from that XML (Less then 3 nodes out of 100)

Is there a way to do it without recreate the schema such as jaxb schema generator?
What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAXB with annotations** may do. JAXB will ignore spurious XML structures.

This of course when you maintain the structure.